# Why "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in itextsharp.dll" can occur and how to solve it

Tags: vb.net, itext

I am using iTextSharp version 5.5. 
I am getting the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in itextsharp.dll" when I want to open the pdf file.

I am getting the error in the last line [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sy2XE.png)
"Dim reader As New PdfReader(_byte)"

```
                        Dim stampFilepath = "~/pdf_temp/" + stampFilename

                        Dim document As New Document()
                        Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(Server.MapPath(stampFilepath), FileMode.Create))
                        document.Open()
                        Dim font As New iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.Font.COURIER, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK)
                        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(writer.DirectContent, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, New Phrase(StampSignautre, font), 200.0F, 30, 0)
                        document.Close()

                        Dim MemStrm As New MemoryStream()
                        Dim _byte As Byte() = st
                        Dim _templateBye As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(stampFilepath))
                        Dim reader As New PdfReader(_byte)
```

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question?

Comment: what is 'st' in your code sample? `Dim _byte As Byte() = st`

Comment: @AConfusedSimpleton 'st' is the byte(). st = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(Path_of_the_pdfFile))

Comment: Is this problem can occur due to a Corrupt PDF file??